# Adding apps sequence in Installed apps section in setting.py in django

Tags: django, django-templates, blogs, web-development-server, django-settings

i wanted to add my blog app templates so i just addes blog.apps.BlogConfig in my installed apps section but here's what i found

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]
adding blog.app at the top section gave an error of "no module name .."
but

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
```

]

adding in the end worked fine ...i wanted to know why did it work and how does this sequence effects and in the tutorial the person added blog.apps.blogConfig at the starting but worked for him(version 2.0) and my version is also the same .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) documentation page, which is about the `contenttypes` module.

> Django includes a contenttypes application that can track all of the models installed in your Django-powered project

For a blog application, you most likely had models in there. Besides, as blogs should belong to a user, you need the `authentication` and `sessions` module; if you used the `{% load static %}` tag in your HTML files, you need the `staticfiles` module.

If you load your application before Django loads its modules, things will not work correctly, and that's why you only load your own things after Django completed loading its own.